# SumoLogic query for checking if IP belongs to lookup of IP ranges provided?

Tags: sumologic

I have created lookup with subnets mentioned in it , how do i search if triggered log's ip belongs to lookup values. Have tried compareCIDRPrefix function but it is taking only one value as string not lookup.